# Timeago.js - Title can't be changed?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, timeago

I am using an HTML Helper to generate the Timestamp.js tags `<abbr>`

```
public static MvcHtmlString TimeAgo(this HtmlHelper html,
                            DateTime dateTime)
{
    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("abbr");
    tagBuilder.SetInnerText(String.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", dateTime));
    tagBuilder.AddCssClass("timeago");
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("title", String.Format("{0:s}Z", dateTime));            
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString());
}
```

The following is generated :

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="July 2, 2014">6 minutes ago</abbr>
```

It's ok, except that I would like to have a full datetime on the title tag, since I found it more useful for the end users.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot friends,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the format in here:

```
tagBuilder.SetInnerText(String.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", dateTime));
```

for example if you need something like: *2014-07-02* you should write *yyyy-MM-dd*

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can find every possible format!